# App Store Connect Create a Profile Errors 500

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am going to generate a profile but the server returns 500 and there are no hints available.

I have no problem with other functions, but when I created the profile, this problem occurred. How should I solve this problem? I sent the email to the apple, but I didn't get a reply.

So is the parameter error causing the server to return 500, or the Apple server has some problems?

So is it a parameter error that causes the server to return 500, or is there a problem with the Apple server? Because I didn't find the relevant sample code, I was unable to determine what caused the problem.

[Endpoint specification document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/create_a_profile)

HTTP Request:

```
POST https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/profiles
```

python code:

```
def registerProfile(token, identifier, udid, certificateID):  
    data = dict(  
        data=dict(  
            type='profiles',  
            attributes=dict(  
                name='xxxxx',  
                profileType='IOS_APP_ADHOC'  
            ),  
            relationships=dict(  
                bundleId=dict(  
                    data=dict(  
                        type='bundleIds',  
                        id=identifier  
                    )  
                ),  
                certificates=dict(  
                    data=dict(            
                        type='certificates',  
                        id=certificateID  
                    )
                ),
                devices=dict(  
                    data=dict(  
                        type='devices',  
                        id=udid  
                    )  
                )  
            )  
        )  
    )  
    result = requestUtils.post(token, URL.registerProfile, data)  
    print(result.text)  
    try:  
        id = json.loads(result.content.decode())['data']['id']  
    except BaseException:  
        return False  
    return id
```

Erroneous response:

```
{  
    "errors": [{  
        "status": "500",  
        "code": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR",  
        "title": "An unexpected error occurred.",  
        "detail": "An unexpected error occurred on the server side. If this issue continues, contact us at https://developer.apple.com/contact/."  
    }]]
}
```

Comment: Why are you defining dicts like that? Why not use `{ }`?

Comment: This is more convenient for me to view

Answer (score 1):

In the **relationships** object, the fields **certificates.data** and **devices.data** are supposed to be arrays, whereas you have defined dictionaries.

See the relevant documentation pages for the fields, respectively:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/profilecreaterequest/data/relationships/certificates

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/profilecreaterequest/data/relationships/devices

Therefore, the following changes ought to be made:

```
 certificates=dict(  
                data=[dict(            
                    type='certificates',  
                    id=certificateID  
                )]
            ),
            devices=dict(  
                data=[dict(  
                    type='devices',  
                    id=udid  
                )]
            )
```

Unfortunately, the API does not return a better error response, and instead just yields a server error. But these changes ought to yield a proper response *(I encountered the same issue as you, and this was the cause of it)*, provided the request resource id's and the headers are correct.